# " InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed " in customkeyboard

Tags: java, android, keyboard, custom-keyboard, long-press

I am developing on custom keyboard . when i long press on a key this log appears.

InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed .

hot can i fix this problem ?

{enter code here}`

```
public class MyKeyboard extends InputMethodService implements      
    KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener ,View.OnClickListener {

   @Override
      public View onCreateInputView () {
      context = getApplicationContext();
      kv = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard_layout , null);
      kv.setKeyboard(qwerty_latin);    
      ic = getCurrentInputConnection();     
      kv.setPreviewEnabled(false);    
      setCandidatesViewShown(true);    
      kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
return kv;
```

}

I have a class that its name is MyKeyboard and another class (MyKeyboardView) that is nowhere initialized (i do not know how and where i should use from it)
so i can not handle Long press and change popup keyboard attribute and handling preview key .

i am Beginner in developing .

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: I am sorry about my English . English is not my language .

Comment: where are you instantiating MyKeyboard

Comment: Nowhere . i just create this class and introduce it as a service in android manifest .

Comment: @Nongthonbam Tonthoi           
 
Nowhere . i just create this class and introduce it as a service in android manifest .